# Dynamic memory allocation for character arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Okay, so I was trying to resize an array as follows :

```
if((editBufferCounter + 20) > editBufferSize)
{
    char* temp;
    temp = new char[editBufferSize + 5];

    strcpy(temp, editBuffer);

    delete[] editBuffer;

    editBufferSize *= 2;  

    editBuffer = new char[editBufferSize];

    strcpy(editBuffer, temp);

    delete[] temp;

}
```

The last line `delete[] temp` causes a memory problem. The program simply crashes. I can't seem to get what the problem here is.

Note:
The program runs fine if i remove the line `delete[] temp;`

Comment: Any reason you mess around with char* instead of std::string?

Comment: Actually no. But my question is related to what is happening here. It beats me why this is happening.

Comment: how do you get the value of editBufferSize? It's possible you're dealing with heap corruption (strcpy?)

Comment: Why the double copy? Just allocate twice the size, copy, free, and set the pointer to the new memory.

Comment: There is something you are not showing us which causes your program to crash.

Comment: @pezcode
This is a part of the function of a class. `editBuffer` is a class data member, and so is `editBufferCounter`. I create `editBuffer` with a size of `editBufferSize`.

Comment: Are you sure editBuffer is 0-terminated?

Comment: @KerrekSB
I will try that. But still, I would like to know what the problem is with the above code snippet

Comment: @pezcode
As a matter of fact it isn't. Holy cow, I really didn't think of that. Lemme check

Comment: Your code is not safe, even after the fix suggested by the accepted answer.  What happens if either call to `new` throws?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley

Thanks for the comment! You are right, but the purpose for my question was to figure out what was happening wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your editBuffer have a terminating NUL character? if not, please replace `strcpy` with `strncpy`.

Comment: I just tried it with `memcpy` and it worked. Is there any advantage of `strncpy` over `memcpy`?

Comment: strncpy copies no more than n characters and memcpy just copies n bytes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Since size of `char` is one byte, is there any other difference?

Comment: When your process undefined length c strings, every time you process a c string, your must adjust the lenght with `memcpy`. when process character array `memcpy` may copy some useless bytes, but `strncpy` doesn't. It means `strncpy` more flexible than `memcpy` , and more secure than `strcpy`.

Comment: @arnkore: `strncpy` has to check for a null-character and zero-pad the destination so it does as much work as `memcpy`. For copying blocks of memory, like devjeetroy's buffer, `memcpy` will typically be faster.

Answer (score 3):

You function can be simplified to:

```
if ((editBufferCounter + 20) > editBufferSize)
{
    char* temp = new char[editBufferSize * 2];

    std::copy_n(editBuffer, editBufferSize, temp);

    delete[] editBuffer;

    editBufferSize *= 2;  

    editBuffer = temp;
}
```